# Codeigniter insert data using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm using Ajax for CRUD. How can I use an associative array for inserting data with Ajax, so I don't have to reload the page and to append the inserted data below the existing data?

---

Here's The JS

```
function addTextBox(section, id_group) {
row_section = "#row_" + section;
wrapper = $(row_section);
// $(wrapper).append('<div class="movement_group"><input type="text" class="title_group" name="title_detail[' + section + ']" placeholder="Input" required="" style="width: 300px" /><button type="button" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm sending">Ok</button><button type="button" onClick="remove_field(\'' + section + '\')" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm remove_content">X</button></div>'); //add input box
// $(wrapper).append('<ul id="' + section + '" class="input_fields" style="list-style-type:none"><li><div class="movement_group"><input type="text" class="title_group" name="title_detail[\'' + section + '\']" placeholder="Input" required="" style="width: 300px" /><button type="button" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm sending">Ok</button><button type="button" onClick="remove_field(\'' + section + '\')" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm remove_content">X</button></div></li></ul>'); //add input box
$(wrapper).append('<ul id="fail_' + section + '" class="input_fields" style="list-style-type:none"><li><div class="movement_group"><input type="text" id="txt_' + section + '" id_group = "' + id_group + '"class="title_group" name="title_detail[\'' + section + '\']" placeholder="Input" required="" style="width: 300px" /><button type="button" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm sending" onClick="saveTitleGroup(\'' + section + '\', \'' + id_group + '\')">Ok</button><button type="button" onClick="remove_field(\'' + section + '\')" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-sm remove_content">X</button></div></li></ul>'); //add input box }

function remove_field(section) {
    section_id = "#fail_" + section;
    $(section_id).remove(); }

function saveTitleGroup(section, id_group) {
title_group = "#txt_" + section;
title_group = $(title_group).val();
td_section = "#td_" + section;
row_section = "#row_section" + section;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: adminUrl+"/interest/save_detail",
data: {title: title_group, interest_group_id: id_group}, 
dataType: "text",
cache:false,
success: 
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('test');
        console.log(row_section);
        /*$('.movement').fadeOut(800, function(){
            $('.movement').fadeIn().delay(500);
                // $('.movement').reload('http://127.0.0.1/camtravel-web/administrator/interest');
                // return data;
                window.location.reload();
        });*/
        // console.log(row_section);
        // console.log(title_group);
        // $('#tableinterest').html('');
        $(td_section).html(data);
        // $(row_section).html(''');
      }
  }); }
```

---

View

```
                <table id="tableinterest" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $n=0;
                        foreach ($interest_groups as $interest_group) {
                    $n++;   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>";
                            // echo $interest_group['id'] . ". " 
                            echo $n . ". ";
                            ?>

                            </td>
                            <?php
                                echo "<td id='td_section_$interest_group[id]' group-id='$interest_group[id]'>";
                                // echo "<div id='title_group_'></div>";
                                echo "<b style='font-size:11pt !important;'>" . $interest_group['title'] . "</b>" . "<span style='margin-left:850px; font-size:15pt;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus interest_add' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Add Detail' onclick='addTextBox(\"section_$interest_group[id]\", \"$interest_group[id]\")'></span><button type='button' style='float:right;' class='btn btn-xs text-red btn-delete-group' data-id='$interest_group[id]' data-category='$interest_group[title]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button> ";
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "</br>";
                                foreach ($interest_details as $interest_detail) {
                                    echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>";
                                    if ($interest_detail['interest_group_id'] == $interest_group['id']) {
                                        echo "<li id='" . $interest_detail['id'] . "'>" . "<label style='font-size:10pt !important;' data-title=\"$interest_detail[title]\" id=\"$interest_detail[id]\" detail_id=\"$interest_group[id]\" class='editme1' id-title='\"$interest_group[id]\"'>" . $interest_detail['title'] . "</label>" .
                                        "<button type='button' style='float:right;' class='btn btn-xs btn-delete-interest text-red' data-id='$interest_detail[id]' data-category='$interest_detail[title]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button>" . "</li>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</ul>";
                                }
                                    /*echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>";
                                    echo "<li id='row_section_$interest_group[id]' class='input_fields'>" . "</li>";
                                    echo "</ul>";*/
                                    echo "<div id='row_section_$interest_group[id]'></div>";
                            echo "</td>";
                            // echo "<tr class='input_content'>";
                            // echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        } 
                        ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

---

Controller

```
    function save_detail(){
    // $id      = $this->input->post('interest_group_id');
    $title      = $this->input->post('title');

    $save = $this->save = $this->interest_group->save();

    if ($save) {
        echo $title;
        // redirect('administrator/interest','refresh');
        $this->layout = false;
    } else {
        echo "save failed";
        // $this->layout = false;
    }

    // $title       = $this->input->post('id-title');
    // echo $title;
}
```

---

Model

```
function save(){

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    // date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

    $data = array(
      "interest_group_id"   => $this->input->post('interest_group_id'),
      "title"               => $this->input->post('title'),
      "created_at"          => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
      "updated_at"          => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    );

  if ($id == null) {
    $save = $this->db->insert('interest_detail',$data);

    if ($save) {
        return true;

      $data                                   = array();
      $data['interest_group_id']              = 'interest_group_id';
      $data['title']                          = 'title';
      // $data['title']                          =

      $data = array("data" => $data);
      $data = json_encode($data);


        $interest_group = $this->get_interest_group_by_id($this->input->post('interest_group_id'));
        $interest_details = $this->get_interest_detail_by_id($this->input->post('interest_group_id'));

        echo "<b>" . $interest_group['title'] . "</b>" . "<span style='margin-left:875px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus interest_add' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Add Detail' onclick='addTextBox(\"section_$interest_group[id]\", \"$interest_group[id]\")'></span><button type='button' style='float:right;' class='btn btn-xs text-red btn-delete-group' data-id='$interest_group[id]' data-category='$interest_group[title]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button> ";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        foreach ($interest_details as $interest_detail) {
            echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>";
            if ($interest_detail['interest_group_id'] == $interest_group['id']) {
                echo "<li>" . "<label class='editme1'>" . $interest_detail['title'] . "</label>" .
                "<button type='button' style='float:right;' class='btn btn-xs btn-delete-interest text-red' data-id='$interest_detail[id]' data-category='$interest_detail[title]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button>" . "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo "<div id='row_section_$interest_group[id]'></div>";

        print_r($interest_group);
        print_r($interest_details);

    } else {
        return false;
    }

  } else {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $update = $this->db->update('interest_detail', $data);

    if ($update) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: sorry forget somethink in the Js

 title_group = "#txt_" + section;
 title_group = $(title_group).val();
 td_section = "#td_" + section;
 row_section = "#row_section" + section;

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: when I add a data, the previous data replaced by the latest row I input

Comment: @RevoirHz add code without images

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes when defining a string `$string = '<div class"dre"></div>'` and associative arrays need quotes names `$array['name']` not `$array[name]` and last properly concatenate the strings and variables.

Try this:

```
<table id="tableinterest" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $n=0;
                        foreach ($interest_groups as $interest_group) {
                    $n++;   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>";
                            // echo $interest_group['id'] . ". " 
                            echo $n . ". ";
                            ?>

                            </td>
                            <?php
                                echo "<td id='td_section_".$interest_group['id']."' group-id='".$interest_group['id']."'>";
                                echo "<b style='font-size:11pt !important;'>" . $interest_group['title'] . "</b>" . '<span style="margin-left:850px; font-size:15pt;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus interest_add" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add Detail" onclick="addTextBox(section_'.$interest_group['id'].','.$interest_group['id'].')"></span><button type="button" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-xs text-red btn-delete-group" data-id='.$interest_group['id'].' data-category="'.$interest_group['title'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button> ';
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "</br>";
                                foreach ($interest_details as $interest_detail) {
                                    echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>";
                                    if ($interest_detail['interest_group_id'] == $interest_group['id']) {
                                        echo "<li id='" . $interest_detail['id'] . "'>" . "<label style='font-size:10pt !important;' data-title=\"".$interest_detail['title']."\" id=\"".$interest_detail['id']."\" detail_id=\"".$interest_group['id']."\" class='editme1' id-title='\"".$interest_group['id']."\"'>" . $interest_detail['title'] . "</label>" .
                                        "<button type='button' style='float:right;' class='btn btn-xs btn-delete-interest text-red' data-id='$interest_detail[id]' data-category='$interest_detail[title]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button>" . "</li>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</ul>";
                                }

                                    echo "<div id='row_section_".$interest_group['id']."'></div>";
                            echo "</td>"
                            echo "</tr>";
                        } 
                        ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: my friend tell, must using array associative and json_encode

Comment: where do you call the js function `saveTitleGroup`?

Comment: There's a js to append textbox and button submit, the button have function onclick call saveTitleGroup

Comment: where do you call `addTextBox`? where are this variables coming from `section, id_group`?

Comment: `row_section = "#row_section" + section;` => `row_section = "#row_" + section;`

Comment: solved thank you, i must append in row of <td> to </td> in ajax response success